# Запятые при пояснении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Почему в этих предложениях обособляется часть предложения после слова "сегодня"? Это можно рассматривать как пояснение?

> Сегодня, после полосы спада, Транссиб на подъеме.
>
> Сегодня, после
> создания теории относительности и многочисленных экспериментов,
> известно, что время может сжиматься, растягиваться и даже
> искривляться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Сегодня,** (когда именно?) ***после*** создания теории относительности и многочисленных экспериментов; **сегодня,** (когда именно?) ***после*** полосы спада — конструкции с предлогом "после" являются уточняющими, они выделяются в предложении запятыми.

Предлог имеет смысл "по окончании чего-либо, позднее чего-либо; вслед за чем-нибудь".
"Сегодня" в предложении имеет значение "сейчас, в данный момент (в данное время)".

Чаще всего уточняются обстоятельства места и **времени** (наш вариант), поскольку именно они могут обозначаться обобщённо и неопределённо (там, туда, оттуда; везде, всюду; тогда, потом...).

Конкретизацию дает именно уточняющий член (он всегда следует за уточняемым):
***Теперь,*** (когда именно?) ***после половодья,*** это была река саженей в шесть (Чехов).

[Уточняющие члены предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)

Answer (score 1):

Да, но не пояснение, а уточнение, указание на обстоятельство, которое имеется в виду.